# RRule JS weekday property not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rrule

I have written following code for getting daily recurrence in my angular, my issue is when I use **byweekday** property of RRule JS, application stuck and does not respond at all. Sometimes it does work but takes huge time to execute code on line `#rrule_after`. Please let me know why is this happening and what can be better solutions for this?

```
function getNextRecurrenceDate(recurrenceVo,rule){
     var startDate = new Date(recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.startDate);
     var today = new Date();
     var calculatedDate = null;
     if(today.getTime() <= startDate.getTime()){
         return startDate;
     }else{
         //#rrule_after - when I debug the code and comes to this function execution, my application stucks/halts for long time and does not response at all
         calculatedDate = rule.after(today,true);
        // this is temporary code I have written to overcome the problem of daily weekday recurrence 
       if(calculatedDate && recurrenceVo.dailyRecurrenceVO && recurrenceVo.dailyRecurrenceVO.everyWeekDay && calculatedDate.getDay() > 4){
             calculatedDate.setDate(calculatedDate.getDate() + (7 - calculatedDate.getDay()));
         }
     }
     return (calculatedDate)?calculatedDate:'';
 }

 function getDailyNextRecurrenceDate(recurrenceVo){
     var rule = new RRule({
          freq: RRule.DAILY,
          interval: recurrenceVo.dailyRecurrenceVO.numberofDays,
          dtstart: new Date(recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.startDate)
     })
     if(recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.endCount){
         rule.options.count = recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.endCount;
     }
     if(recurrenceVo.dailyRecurrenceVO.everyWeekDay){
        rule.options.interval = 1;
        // When I remove this code then all working fine and application not halting at all
        rule.options.byweekday = [RRule.MO, RRule.TU, RRule.WE, RRule.TH, RRule.FR]
     }
     if(recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.endDate){
         rule.options.until = new Date(recurrenceVo.recurrenceRangeVO.endDate);
     }
     var nextRecDate = getNextRecurrenceDate(recurrenceVo,rule);
     return nextRecDate?nextRecDate.setHours(0,0,0,0):'';
 }
```

Comment: You probably should open a ticket on the library's bug tracking system instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @rlanvin but my only concern was if somebody has faced this problem before, so I could get the solution. Anyways, I'll take your point!

Comment: Seems like this could be related to this (still unresolved) known issue of RRule:
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/issues/409